# How to assign value inside list comprehension

Tags: python, oop, list-comprehension

How to assign a value to object's .ID attribute from [inside of a list comprehension]?

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self): 
        self.ID=0

l=[C() for i in range(4)]
print l

t=[c for c in l if c.ID+1]
for c in t: print c.ID,
```

> [<**main**.C object at 0x10454de50>, <**main**.C object at
>   0x10454ded0>, <**main**.C object at 0x10454df90>, <**main**.C object
>   at 0x10455b150>]
>
> 0 0 0 0
>
> [Finished in 0.1s]

## edit

How to change `i` with list comprehension:

```
l=[i for i in range(4)]
i=0
t=[c for c in l if i++]
print i
```

Comment: why do you want that?

Comment: Now you're asking a different question.

Comment: trying to extend the original subject to on how to write to "external" variable from inside comprehension without using a left-most space..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a simple function do perform the transformation:

```
def foo(c):
    c.ID += 1
    return c
```

Then use it in the list comprehension:

```
>>> t=[foo(c) for c in l]
>>> for c in t: print c.ID,
1 1 1 1
>>> for c in l: print c.ID,
1 1 1 1
```

Note that it may be a good idea to add an ID parameter to `C`'s constructor, so you can construct C objects with any ID you want:

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self, ID=0): 
        self.ID=ID
```

Then

```
>>> a = [c(42) for _ in xrange(4)]
>>> b = [c(i) for i in xrange(4)]
>>> for c in a: print c.ID,
42 42 42 42
>>> for c in b: print c.ID,
>>> 0 1 2 3
```